# How to propagate the name change of Form's UI controls's throughtout all the .cs in project

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring, uicontrol

In C# , Winform, I have created a form and bunch of UI controls on it.    I have changed the name of the controls through Properties windows but the following automated generated code did not update automatically.  However, the InitializeComponent code is automatically updated though.  My problem is now that I don't remember which box or whihc label I renamed to certain name..  Two questions : How could I have done this more efficiently to begin with?  Question 2) Is there anything I could do now to make it automatically change the corresponding names?  I have heard of refactoring but I don't know if I could have used it here and how?   I appreciate any help.

```
public partial class frmMyInterface : Form
{
    public frmMyInterface()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmMyInterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: "textBox1" is no match for "textBox1_Click".  You'll have to rename these methods separately.  Right-click + Refactor + Rename.  I'd assume the next time you'll spend more time picking good names at design time.

Comment: There is no automated way to do this that I'm aware of. The best course of action is preventive. Give your controls appropriate names before writing any code for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename each these event handlers and then on the property window, reassign the events selecting from the dropdrown.  Or delete these event handlers and double click on each event in the property window and this time it will update it for you